# Httplistener and file upload

Tags: c#, parsing, streamreader, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I am trying to retrieve an uploaded file from my webserver. As the client sends its files through a webform (random files), I need to parse the request to get the file out and to process it further on. 
Basically, the code goes as:

```
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
// this is the retrieved file from streamreader
string file = null;

while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null){
     // i read the stream till i retrieve the filename
     // get the file data out and break the loop 
}
// A byststream is created by converting the string,
Byte[] bytes = request.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(file);
MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

// do the rest
```

As a result, i am able to retrieve textfiles, but for all other files, they are corrupted.
Could someone tell me how to parse these HttplistnerRequests properly (or providing a lightweighted alternative)?

Comment: I take it you're using enctype="multipart/form-data" in your web form? If so it looks like you're oversimplifying the way you read the content.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are making things harder on yourself than necessary by doing this with an `HttpListener` rather than using the built in facilities of ASP.Net. But if you must do it this way here is some sample code. Note: 1) I'm assuming you're using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>`. 2) This code is designed to be used with a form containing only your `<input type="file" />` if you want to post other fields or multiple files you'll have to change the code. 3) This is meant to be a proof of concept/example, it may have bugs, and is not particularly flexible.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/ListenerTest/");
    listener.Start();

    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

    SaveFile(context.Request.ContentEncoding, GetBoundary(context.Request.ContentType), context.Request.InputStream);

    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        writer.WriteLine("File Uploaded");

    context.Response.Close();

    listener.Stop();

}

private static String GetBoundary(String ctype)
{
    return "--" + ctype.Split(';')[1].Split('=')[1];
}

private static void SaveFile(Encoding enc, String boundary, Stream input)
{
    Byte[] boundaryBytes = enc.GetBytes(boundary);
    Int32 boundaryLen = boundaryBytes.Length;

    using (FileStream output = new FileStream("data", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
        Int32 len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
        Int32 startPos = -1;

        // Find start boundary
        while (true)
        {
            if (len == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Start Boundaray Not Found");
            }

            startPos = IndexOf(buffer, len, boundaryBytes);
            if (startPos >= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Array.Copy(buffer, len - boundaryLen, buffer, 0, boundaryLen);
                len = input.Read(buffer, boundaryLen, 1024 - boundaryLen);
            }
        }

        // Skip four lines (Boundary, Content-Disposition, Content-Type, and a blank)
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (len == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Preamble not Found.");
                }

                startPos = Array.IndexOf(buffer, enc.GetBytes("\n")[0], startPos);
                if (startPos >= 0)
                {
                    startPos++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                }
            }
        }

        Array.Copy(buffer, startPos, buffer, 0, len - startPos);
        len = len - startPos;

        while (true)
        {
            Int32 endPos = IndexOf(buffer, len, boundaryBytes);
            if (endPos >= 0)
            {
                if (endPos > 0) output.Write(buffer, 0, endPos-2);
                break;
            }
            else if (len <= boundaryLen)
            {
                throw new Exception("End Boundaray Not Found");
            }
            else
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, len - boundaryLen);
                Array.Copy(buffer, len - boundaryLen, buffer, 0, boundaryLen);
                len = input.Read(buffer, boundaryLen, 1024 - boundaryLen) + boundaryLen;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static Int32 IndexOf(Byte[] buffer, Int32 len, Byte[] boundaryBytes)
{
    for (Int32 i = 0; i <= len - boundaryBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        Boolean match = true;
        for (Int32 j = 0; j < boundaryBytes.Length && match; j++)
        {
            match = buffer[i + j] == boundaryBytes[j];
        }

        if (match)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

To help you better understand what the code above is doing, here is what the body of the HTTP POST looks like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9lcB0OZVXSqZLbmv

------WebKitFormBoundary9lcB0OZVXSqZLbmv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_file"; filename="Test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Test
------WebKitFormBoundary9lcB0OZVXSqZLbmv--
```

I've left out the irrelevant headers. As you can see, you need to parse the body by scanning through to find the beginning and ending boundary sequences, and drop the sub headers that come before the content of your file. Unfortunately you cannot use StreamReader because of the potential for binary data. Also unfortunate is the fact that there is no per file Content-Length (the Content-Length header for the request specifies the total length of the body including boundaries, sub-headers, and spacing.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this elaborated response! It is indeed working and helps me a lot! (even if this is not the most efficient way)

Comment: solved my problem. But has to modify a bit if the stream has no boundary. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PaulWheeler Using your code above, the target files I transfer always have 2 bytes more than the original. This does not matter for jpg files, they still display fine, but zip files say that the CRC is not correct and when unzipping, some file is always corrupt. With all files, regardless of sizes, it's always 2 additional bytes. Any idea where they are coming from? (On Win8.1).

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, note that I edited your answer/code, as per my finding in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744879/c-sharp-httplistener-storing-posted-file-is-always-2-byte-larger-than-original

Comment: This works great for situations where access to ASP.NET is not available.  Thanks for showing us how to do it the hard way.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `StreamReader` because it is meant to read streams in which the bytes are in the UTF8. Instead, you want to read the contents of the stream to a receive buffer, remove all the stuff you don't need, get the file extension of the uploaded file, extract the contents of the uploaded file, then save the file contents to a new file. The code I show in this post assumes your form looks like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/uploader">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

As you can see, the code is only meant to handle a form that only has the file. Since there is no way to extract the contents of a file on the server from a application/x-www-form-urlencoded form, so you have to include the "multipart/form-data".

First, for this method of handling uploaded files, you will first need this little bit of code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Second, you need to read the contents of the `request.InputStream` to a receive buffer, or a `byte[]`. We do this by making a `byte[]` buffer with the length of the `Content-Length` header sent by the browser. Then, we read the contents of the `request.InputStream` to the buffer. The code would look like this:

```
int len = int.Parse(request.Headers["Content-Length"]);
byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, len);
```

The stream will look somewhat like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9lcB0OZVXSqZLbmv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="example-file.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

file contents here
------WebKitFormBoundary9lcB0OZVXSqZLbmv--
```

Next, you need to get the file extension of the uploaded file. We can do this using this code:

```
string fileExtension = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).Split("\r\n")[1].Split("filename=\"")[1].Replace("\"", "").Split('.')[^1];
```

Then, we need to get the contents of the file. We do this by removing the stuff at the beginning (the -----WebKitFormBoundary, the Content-Disposition, the Content-Type, and a blank line), then removing the last line of the request body, plus an extra `\r\n` at the end. Here is the code that does just that:

```
// note that the variable buffer is the byte[], and the variable bytes is the List<byte>
string stringBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>(buffer);
string[] splitString = stringBuffer.Split('\n');
int lengthOfFourLines = splitString[0].Length + splitString[1].Length + 
splitString[2].Length + splitString[3].Length + 4;
bytes.RemoveRange(0, lengthOfFourLines);
int lengthOfLastLine = splitString[^2].Length+2;
bytes.RemoveRange(bytes.Count - lengthOfLastLine, lengthOfLastLine);
buffer = bytes.ToArray();
```

Finally, we need to save the contents to a file. The code below generates a random file name with the user-specified file extension, and saves the files contents to it.

```
string fname = "";
string[] chars = "q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l z x c v b n m Q W E R T Y U I O P A S D F G H J K L Z X C V B N M 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".Split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    fname += chars[new Random().Next(chars.Length)];
}
fname += fileExtension;
FileStream file = File.Create(fname);
file.Write(buffer);
file.Close();
```

Here is the whole code put together:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/");
    listener.Start();
    while(true)
    {
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        if(request.HttpMethod=="POST") SaveFile(request);
        response.OutputStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("file successfully uploaded"));
        response.OutputStream.Close();
    }
}
void SaveFile(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    int len = (int)request.ContentLength64;
    Console.WriteLine(len);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
    request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, len);
    string stringBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    Console.WriteLine(stringBuffer.Replace("\r\n","\\r\\n\n"));
    string fileExtension = stringBuffer.Split("\r\n")[1]
        .Split("filename=\"")[1]
        .Replace("\"", "")
        .Split('.')[^1]
    ;
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>(buffer);
    string[] splitString = stringBuffer.Split('\n');
    int lengthOfFourLines = splitString[0].Length + splitString[1].Length + splitString[2].Length + splitString[3].Length + 4;
    bytes.RemoveRange(0, lengthOfFourLines);
    int lengthOfLastLine = splitString[^2].Length+2;
    bytes.RemoveRange(bytes.Count - lengthOfLastLine, lengthOfLastLine);
    buffer = bytes.ToArray();
    
    string fname = "";
    string[] chars = "q w e r t y u i o p a s d f g h j k l z x c v b n m Q W E R T Y U I O P A S D F G H J K L Z X C V B N M 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0".Split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fname += chars[new Random().Next(chars.Length)];
    }
    fname += "." + fileExtension;
    FileStream file = File.Create(fname);
    file.Write(buffer);
    file.Close();
}
```

Also, if you want to send an uploaded file to the client, here is a useful function that sends the file to the client.

```
// Make sure you are using System.IO, and System.Net when making this function.
// Also make sure you set the content type of the response before calling this function.
// fileName is the name of the file you want to send to the client, and output is the response.OutputStream.
public static void SendFile(string fileName, Stream output)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    fs.CopyTo(output);
    fs.Close();
    output.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are reading the file as text.

You need to read the file as a bytearray instead and using the [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) is better and easier to use than `StreamReader`:

```
Byte[] bytes;
using (System.IO.BinaryReader r = new System.IO.BinaryReader(request.InputStream))
{
    // Read the data from the stream into the byte array
    bytes = r.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(request.InputStream.Length));
}
MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!
It seems however that the request.InputStream.Length provides a not supported exception.
Furthermore, bytearray complicates the job as there is some parsing that needs to take place to extract the file from other body content. Streamrider seemed from that perspective better fit for purpose.

Comment: @user1092608: Oh, that's unfortunate. The problem is that you can't really use the text read capabilities of streamreader to extract a binary file. Are you using a FileUpload control or some other method to embed the file in the stream?

Comment: That is a pertinent remark. 
Right now the client basically uses the default html <input type="file" name="datafile" ..> form. If possible, i would like to avoid the fileUpload control, to keep things as simple as possible -wathever this still means-. 
In this project, another instance (machine) should be able to throw random files at my server, along with some metadata,  to do stuff with it and post the results back.

Comment: @user1092608: In this case, I would separate the receipt of the file from the processing into separate methods. I think the only way you are going to successfully receive a binary file from the user is to use the actual methods from the file input control. Once you have received the file, you can pass it to your common file-handling mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

May have bugs, test thoroughly.  This one gets all post, get, and files.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace DUSTLauncher
{
    class HttpNameValueCollection
    {
        public class File
        {
            private string _fileName;
            public string FileName { get { return _fileName ?? (_fileName = ""); } set { _fileName = value; } }

            private string _fileData;
            public string FileData { get { return _fileData ?? (_fileName = ""); } set { _fileData = value; } }

            private string _contentType;
            public string ContentType { get { return _contentType ?? (_contentType = ""); } set { _contentType = value; } }
        }

        private NameValueCollection _get;
        private Dictionary<string, File> _files;
        private readonly HttpListenerContext _ctx;

        public NameValueCollection Get { get { return _get ?? (_get = new NameValueCollection()); } set { _get = value; } }
        public NameValueCollection Post { get { return _ctx.Request.QueryString; } }
        public Dictionary<string, File> Files { get { return _files ?? (_files = new Dictionary<string, File>()); } set { _files = value; } }

        private void PopulatePostMultiPart(string post_string)
        {
            var boundary_index = _ctx.Request.ContentType.IndexOf("boundary=") + 9;
            var boundary = _ctx.Request.ContentType.Substring(boundary_index, _ctx.Request.ContentType.Length - boundary_index);

            var upper_bound = post_string.Length - 4;

            if (post_string.Substring(2, boundary.Length) != boundary)
                throw (new InvalidDataException());

            var raw_post_strings = new List<string>();
            var current_string = new StringBuilder();

            for (var x = 4 + boundary.Length; x < upper_bound; ++x)
            {
                if (post_string.Substring(x, boundary.Length) == boundary)
                {
                    x += boundary.Length + 1;
                    raw_post_strings.Add(current_string.ToString().Remove(current_string.Length - 3, 3));
                    current_string.Clear();
                    continue;
                }

                current_string.Append(post_string[x]);

                var post_variable_string = current_string.ToString();

                var end_of_header = post_variable_string.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n");

                if (end_of_header == -1) throw (new InvalidDataException());

                var filename_index = post_variable_string.IndexOf("filename=\"", 0, end_of_header);
                var filename_starts = filename_index + 10;
                var content_type_starts = post_variable_string.IndexOf("Content-Type: ", 0, end_of_header) + 14;
                var name_starts = post_variable_string.IndexOf("name=\"") + 6;
                var data_starts = end_of_header + 4;

                if (filename_index == -1) continue;

                var filename = post_variable_string.Substring(filename_starts, post_variable_string.IndexOf("\"", filename_starts) - filename_starts);
                var content_type = post_variable_string.Substring(content_type_starts, post_variable_string.IndexOf("\r\n", content_type_starts) - content_type_starts);
                var file_data = post_variable_string.Substring(data_starts, post_variable_string.Length - data_starts);
                var name = post_variable_string.Substring(name_starts, post_variable_string.IndexOf("\"", name_starts) - name_starts);
                Files.Add(name, new File() { FileName = filename, ContentType = content_type, FileData = file_data });
                continue;

            }
        }

        private void PopulatePost()
        {
            if (_ctx.Request.HttpMethod != "POST" || _ctx.Request.ContentType == null) return;

            var post_string = new StreamReader(_ctx.Request.InputStream, _ctx.Request.ContentEncoding).ReadToEnd();

            if (_ctx.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("multipart/form-data"))
                PopulatePostMultiPart(post_string);
            else
                Get = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(post_string);

        }

        public HttpNameValueCollection(ref HttpListenerContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
            PopulatePost();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You are holding file data in string type. Be careful, you are dealing with binary and you must consider big files.

Answer (score 1):

I like @paul-wheeler answer. However I needed to modify their code to include some additional data (In this case, the directory structure).

I'm using this code to upload files:

```
var myDropzone = $("#fileDropZone");
myDropzone.dropzone(
    {
        url: "http://" + self.location.hostname + "/Path/Files.html,
        method: "post",
        createImageThumbnails: true,
        previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#previewTemplateId').innerHTML,
        clickable: false,
        init: function () {
            this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
                // xhr is XMLHttpRequest
                var name = file.fullPath;
                if (typeof (file.fullPath) === "undefined") {
                    name = file.name;
                }

                formData.append('fileNameWithPath', name);
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is @paul-wheeler modified code. Thanks @paul-wheeler.

```
public class FileManager
{
    public static void SaveFile(HttpListenerRequest request, string savePath)
    {
        var tempFileName = Path.Combine(savePath, $"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.tmp");
        if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
        }

        var (res, fileName) = SaveTmpFile(request, tempFileName);
        if (res)
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(savePath, fileName);
            var fileDir = filePath.Substring(0, filePath.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));
            if (!Directory.Exists(fileDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDir);
            }

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }

            File.Move(tempFileName, filePath);
        }
    }

    private static (bool, string) SaveTmpFile(HttpListenerRequest request, string tempFileName)
    {
        var enc = request.ContentEncoding;
        var boundary = GetBoundary(request.ContentType);
        var input = request.InputStream;

        byte[] boundaryBytes = enc.GetBytes(boundary);
        var boundaryLen = boundaryBytes.Length;

        using (FileStream output = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            var len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            var startPos = -1;

            // Get file name and relative path
            var strBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
            var strStart = strBuffer.IndexOf("fileNameWithPath") + 21;
            if (strStart < 21)
            {
                Logger.LogError("File name not found");
                return (false, null);
            }

            var strEnd = strBuffer.IndexOf(boundary, strStart) - 2;
            var fileName = strBuffer.Substring(strStart, strEnd - strStart);
            fileName = fileName.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

            // Find start boundary
            while (true)
            {
                if (len == 0)
                {
                    Logger.LogError("Find start boundary not found");
                    return (false, null);
                }

                startPos = IndexOf(buffer, len, boundaryBytes);
                if (startPos >= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Array.Copy(buffer, len - boundaryLen, buffer, 0, boundaryLen);
                    len = input.Read(buffer, boundaryLen, 1024 - boundaryLen);
                }
            }

            // Advance to data
            var foundData = false;
            while (!foundData)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (len == 0)
                    {
                        Logger.LogError("Preamble not Found");
                        return (false, null);
                    }

                    startPos = Array.IndexOf(buffer, enc.GetBytes("\n")[0], startPos);
                    if (startPos >= 0)
                    {
                        startPos++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // In case read in line is longer than buffer
                        len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                    }
                }

                var currStr = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer).Substring(startPos);
                if (currStr.StartsWith("Content-Type:"))
                {
                    // Go past the last carriage-return\line-break. (\r\n)
                    startPos = Array.IndexOf(buffer, enc.GetBytes("\n")[0], startPos) + 3;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Array.Copy(buffer, startPos, buffer, 0, len - startPos);
            len = len - startPos;

            while (true)
            {
                var endPos = IndexOf(buffer, len, boundaryBytes);
                if (endPos >= 0)
                {
                    if (endPos > 0) output.Write(buffer, 0, endPos - 2);
                    break;
                }
                else if (len <= boundaryLen)
                {
                    Logger.LogError("End Boundaray Not Found");
                    return (false, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, len - boundaryLen);
                    Array.Copy(buffer, len - boundaryLen, buffer, 0, boundaryLen);
                    len = input.Read(buffer, boundaryLen, 1024 - boundaryLen) + boundaryLen;
                }
            }

            return (true, fileName);
        }
    }

    private static int IndexOf(byte[] buffer, int len, byte[] boundaryBytes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= len - boundaryBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            var match = true;
            for (var j = 0; j < boundaryBytes.Length && match; j++)
            {
                match = buffer[i + j] == boundaryBytes[j];
            }

            if (match)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private static string GetBoundary(string ctype)
    {
        return "--" + ctype.Split(';')[1].Split('=')[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

    
var contentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(context.Request.ContentType);
var boundary = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentType.Boundary).Value;
var multipartReader = new MultipartReader(boundary, context.Request.InputStream);
var section = (await multipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync()).AsFileSection();

var fileName = section.FileName;
var fileStream = section.FileStream;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

for a given `HttpListenerRequest req` and a `string path` the following code saves a file (worked for text file but also png file)

```cs
int len = (int)req.ContentLength64;
                         
byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
int totalRead = 0;
while(totalRead < len){
    // InputStream.Read does not read always read full stream (so loop until it has)
    totalRead += req.InputStream.Read(buffer, totalRead, len - totalRead);
}
string stringBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                            
string startTag = stringBuffer.Substring(0, stringBuffer.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 4);
string endTag = stringBuffer.Substring(stringBuffer.IndexOf("\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary"));

List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>(buffer);
bytes = bytes.GetRange(startTag.Length, len - (startTag.Length + endTag.Length));
                            
buffer = bytes.ToArray();

File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);
```

*(build on top of copee moo solution)*

Answer (score 0):

```
static string ReadFileContentNullable(in string header)
{
 if (header == null)
    return null;

unchecked 
{
    const short maxHeaderSizeBytes = 2048;
    const byte zero = 0, six = 6, one = 1, two = 2;
    const char r = '\r', n = '\n';
    const string mime = "text/plain";
    int? len = header?.Length;

    if (len == null || len < six || len > maxHeaderSizeBytes / sizeof(char))
        return null;

    bool found = false, equal = false;
    string boundary = "=----";
    int i = zero, patternLength = boundary.Length, j = zero, k = zero, l = patternLength - one;

    while (i != len && !found)
    {               
        j = i + l;
        ++i;
        k = l;
        equal = true;

        while(k > zero && equal)
            if (header[j--] != boundary[k--])
                equal = false;
        
        if (equal)
            found = true;
    }
    
    if (i == len)
        return null;

    StringBuilder sb = new (len.Value);
    sb.Clear();
    sb.Append("--");

    while(i != len && (header[i + one] != r || header[i + two] != n))
        sb.Append(header[i++]);
    
    sb.Append(header[i]);    

    if (i == len)
        return null;
    
    if (++i == len) 
        return null;

    boundary = sb.ToString();
    sb.Clear();

    while(i != len && (header[i] == r || header[i] == n))
        ++i;

    if (++i == len) 
        return null;

    patternLength = boundary.Length;    
    i += patternLength + one;    

    if (i + patternLength + one > len)
        return null;

    patternLength = mime.Length;

    if (i + patternLength + one > len)
        return null;

    found = false; 
    equal = true;

    while (i != len && !found)
    {                
        j = i + patternLength - one;
        ++i;
        k = patternLength - one;
        equal = true;

        while(k > zero && equal)
            if (header[j--] != mime[k--])
                equal = false;
        
        if (equal)
            found = true;
    }

    if (!found)
        return null;

    i += patternLength + one;

    while(i != len && (header[i] == r || header[i] == n))
        ++i;

    if (i == len)
        return null;

    found = false;
    equal = true;    
    boundary = string.Concat("\r\n", boundary, "--");
    patternLength = boundary.Length;

    while (i != len && !found)
    {                      
        j = i + patternLength;
        sb.Append(header[i++]);
        k = patternLength - one;
        equal = true;

        while(k > zero && equal)
            if (header[j--] != boundary[k--])
                equal = false;
        
        if (equal)
            found = true;
    }

    if (!found)
        return null;

    return sb.ToString();
}
}
```

It's adjusted code from my pet project. Calling convention:

```
string result = ReadFileContentNullable(context?.Request?.ContentType);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
        System.Console.WriteLine("success");
```