# Read file in C# sent with Requests Python

Tags: c#, python-requests, httplistenerrequest

I'm trying to read a file `test.txt` using C# that I send using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) in Python :

**test.txt**

> Hello

**Client.py**

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://localhost:1234/'
    headers = {'auth':'myAuth'}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,files={'test.txt':open('./test.txt','rb')})
    print r.text
```

Then I try to retrieve the data on the server side in C# :

**Server.cs**

```
[...]
public void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    Stream mStream = myHttpRequest.InputStream;
    int content_size = int.Parse(myHttpRequest.Headers["content-length"]);
    byte[] data = new BinaryReader(mStream).ReadBytes(content_size);
    string str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

What I get from the `Console.WriteLine(str)` is :
[image]

But I don't manage to get only the `Hello` part. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466703/httplistener-and-file-upload) working by modifying the following lines :

```
// Skip four lines (Boundary, Content-Disposition, Content-Type, and a blank)
for (Int32 i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

to

```
// Skip 3 lines (Boundary, Content-Disposition and a blank)
for (Int32 i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```