# Parsing multipart form data on .NET

Tags: c#, http, f#, multipartform-data

I have a simple web server using `HttpListener` and I just added some HTML that lets the user upload a file, along the lines of [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

My server receives an HTTP request with the method `POST` as expected and the input stream contains something of this form:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKmI6YLDrfViLaOWc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="CableHook.scad"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

$fn=90;
...
}

------WebKitFormBoundaryKmI6YLDrfViLaOWc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Upload
------WebKitFormBoundaryKmI6YLDrfViLaOWc--
```

How do I parse the multipart form data on .NET to recover the file that the client uploaded to the server?

I have tried this:

```
use content = StreamContent(request.InputStream)
content.Headers.ContentType <- Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse "multipart/form-data"
let provider = content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result
```

but it dies with the error:

```
Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a 'multipart'
content-type header with a 'boundary' parameter.
```

Comment: This is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466703/httplistener-and-file-upload

Comment: Why are you assigning something to content.Headers.ContentType? Won't the header value that was submitted be in the input stream? In any event, you're just assigning the string "multipart/form-data", which is incomplete (as the error message says).