# Why differ file byte array?

Tags: android, kotlin

I developed an Android application,where the user can upload a file to the server.

A send the file with multipart data. Althought the api creats the file, but it is corrupted, I can't open it.

If I send the file via postman, the file in the server is good, and I can open it.

I checked the original, and the newly created file, and i noticed that, the new file is bigger than the original with 2 bytes.After that I compared the 2 files byte codes, and if I skip the first 2 byte in the new one, than the 2 byte array are the same.

So why get 2 extra byte the new file?

I created the api function based on this answer: [Httplistener and file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466703/httplistener-and-file-upload/8468520)

```
**Api interface**

    @Multipart
    @POST("...")
    suspend fun saveOrUpdateDocument2(@Query("name") name: String, @Query("extension") extension: String, @Part file: MultipartBody.Part): ResponseBody

**Function:** 
            context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.let {
                val bytes = it.readBytes()

                val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"),bytes)
                val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",documentUploadDto.originalFileName,requestFile)
                api.saveOrUpdateDocument2(documentUploadDto.originalFileName,documentUploadDto.extension,body)
            }
```

Comment: What is the value of bytes.length?

Comment: In android it is 70568 Byte

Comment: So, I puted my theory into practice. I cuted the first 2 byte from the array on server, and the file is perfect.But I still dont know why, because on the linked solution only the last 2 byte was cut off.

Comment: 70568? And? Why dont you comment? Pretty uninteresting to know only one value. Why did i ask do you think? Think!

Comment: Sorry, I dont underatand what do you mean.It is possible, that the byte array first two byte is a white space, after I cut off the boundary? I am really would like to underatand whats going on.

Comment: Incredible. The question was where you saw that 70568 before? Or do you see it now?