# Powershell httplistener how to handle multipart/form Data

Tags: powershell, file-upload, httplistener

i try to get my upload script working i have build an httplistener i want to upload a file throug it and store it on a local folder on my server.

Lets say the request is here and the body is already stored in a variable called **$body**

if i output the body with: write-host $body i get this:

`------WebKitFormBoundary9Eex9ygmI0hBmi2P Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2021-09-22 09_11_58-Window.png" Content-Type: image/png Some Binary data..... ------WebKitFormBoundary9Eex9ygmI0hBmi2P--`

Now how to store this data as a file again?
If i Try this:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('c:\test.png', $body)
```

I get this error:

> $body cannot converted to "System.Byte". Error: "wrong Format.

Thanks for advice

**More Info:**

This is the request comming in:

```
RequestTraceIdentifier : 00000000-0000-0000-1600-0080000000fe
AcceptTypes            : {text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, image/avif...}
ContentEncoding        : System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding
ContentLength64        : 59956
ContentType            : multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygWVUZ443T8Itaxsv
Headers                : {sec-ch-ua, sec-ch-ua-mobile, sec-ch-ua-platform, Upgrade-Insecure-Requests...}
HttpMethod             : POST
InputStream            : System.Net.HttpRequestStream
IsAuthenticated        : False
IsLocal                : True
IsSecureConnection     : False
IsWebSocketRequest     : False
QueryString            : {}
RawUrl                 : /api/files/upload
ServiceName            : 
Url                    : http://localhost:8888/api/files/upload
UrlReferrer            : http://localhost:8888/files/upload
UserAgent              : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
                         Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
UserHostAddress        : [::1]:8888
UserHostName           : localhost:8888
UserLanguages          : {de-DE, de;q=0.9, en-US;q=0.8, en;q=0.7}
ClientCertificateError : 
TransportContext       : System.Net.HttpListenerRequestContext
Cookies                : {sessionToken=epKsjr9UJvTEBWiFylIPZN8OoQ6Yatbf}
ProtocolVersion        : 1.1
HasEntityBody          : True
KeepAlive              : True
RemoteEndPoint         : [::1]:57320
LocalEndPoint          : [::1]:8888
```

Stored in:
$script:Request

then following function gets the body from Request:

```
function Invoke-GetBody
{
    <#
    .DESCRIPTION
        This function retrieves the Data from the HTTP Listener Body property.
    .EXAMPLE
        Invoke-GetBody
    .NOTES
        This will return a Body object.
    #>
    if ($script:Request.HasEntityBody)
    {
        $script:RawBody = $script:Request.InputStream
        $Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader @($script:RawBody, $script:ContentEncoding)
        $script:Body = $Reader.ReadToEnd()
        $Reader.close()
        $script:Body
    }
    else
    {
        $script:Body = "null"
        $script:Body
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to extract the part that you've replaced with `Some Binary data......` in the sample output, and potentially decode it. Please show us the code with which you obtained `$body`

Comment: Ist there Powershell function for that? Ist the Layout Always the Same? 4 Lines beginning,Data,  Last line

Comment: You could extract the data from that string, convert it to a byte array and save it as a valid file - BUT - a better solution would be to figure out why your returning more than just the HTTP body in your `$body` variable from your HTTPListener (`Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` are HTTP headers which shouldnt be in the body). Provide code or explain how your HTTPListener is capturing the request - thats the source of your issue. The code and error provided so far are not useful to debug this (edit your question with extra info)

Comment: OK have added more informations. 
Do you mean that the function getting the body, have to handle the multipart data in another way?

Comment: Ok after reading a bunch of Articles i still dont know what exactly to do in powershell to get the multipart data. I know now i have to get the binary data of the request and then parse this data somehow...but is there realy no builtin powershell .net function to do this?
Heres a c# example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466703/httplistener-and-file-upload