# Parse POST parameters from HttpListener

Tags: c#, http, post, httplistener

Let's say i have HttpListener. It listen some port and ip. When i send POST request it catch it. How can i parse POST parameters from HttpListenerRequest?

```
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

if ( request.HttpMethod == "POST" )
{
  // Here i can read all parameters in string but how to parse each one i don't know                                            
}
```

Comment: What isn't answered here? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.aspx)

Comment: You don't need to parse it..There properties for it in `HttpListenerRequest`
`request.QueryString`,`request.ContentType`,`request.Headers`...

Comment: Also have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197579/getting-form-data-from-httplistenerrequest

Comment: @KevinDTimm I don't see any methods or properties that can get POST params in key value pairs. Maybe i missed something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The POST body (read from the InputStream on the HttpListenerRequest) is parsed using whatever mechanism you choose to encode the POST data with.

For example, you could be sending JSON using JSON.stringify calls on a JavaScript object in a browser.  In that case you could use the JSON deserializer in .Net or JSON.Net.

Or, you might choose to send XML, or CSV, or something else entirely.

Hope that helps - Harold

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved problem by using json in request.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this issue a few hours ago and banged out this answer hoping it helps someone when parsing out POST data

```
//using System.Web and Add a Reference to System.Web
Dictionary<string, string> postParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] rawParams = rawData.Split('&');
foreach (string param in rawParams)
{
    string[] kvPair = param.Split('=');
    string key = kvPair[0];
    string value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(kvPair[1]);
    postParams.Add(key, value);
}

//Usage
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + postParams["username"]);
```

Comment: What if you have the symbol "&" in the raw response? say
{ "name" : "Slug & Lettuce" }

Comment: @Bruno Late reply however could be useful for others, "&" in raw response should be encoded which is why `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` has been used. "&" should be sent as "&amp;"

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are saved me!

Answer (score 3):

I am a newbie in Web application so I am not sure whether mine is a correct answer but to parse parameters in request, you can do as below:

```
    HttpListenerRequest request = httpListenerContext.Request;

    string val;
    foreach (string keys in request.QueryString.AllKeys)
        val = request.QueryString[keys];
```

Comment: You nailed it. Simple.