# Catch Post from webpage

Tags: c#, html

I'm making a small program to retrieve a post from my webpage.

In my pagepage i have a form with 2 textboxes and 1 'submit' button.

In my c# i have the code to make the page run on a server.
How can i make it that when the user of the webpage presses a button i can get the POST data from the webpage and show to with a `Console.Writeline();`

Can someone explain to me how i can accomplish this.

The code to load the webpage from my server:

```
static HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
static Stream _ouput;

public static void StartListening()
{
    //create new Httplistener
    string localPrefix = "http://localhost:8000/";
    _listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
    _listener.Prefixes.Add(localPrefix);

    _listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening....");
}

public static void GetContext()
{
    // De GetContext methode blokkeert terwijl die wacht op een aanvraag(request)
    HttpListenerContext context = _listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
    string html = Properties.Resources.index;

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    _ouput = response.OutputStream;
    _ouput.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

public static void StopListening()
{
    _ouput.Close();
    _listener.Close();
}
```

**Edit**
After some comments i've got my code done. One small problem, my html form doesn't submit the content of the form.

How can i make my javascript submit its data, and can i catch it with my c# code

Comment: This may be helpful to you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599978/An-HttpListener-Server-for-Handling-AJAX-POST-Requ

Comment: Thx for the link, but when i hit the submit button on my webpage no data is recived in my c# program.

Comment: @HuyHoangPham Can you help me with that

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, first of all **YES** you can use your code to catch the data.
But you have a small problem in your htmlListener. Its a one tyime function, and with that i mean you can only connect once.

You could do something like this:

```
public bool Listening = true;

public static void GetContext()
{
    while (Listening)
    {
        // De GetContext methode blokkeert terwijl die wacht op een aanvraag(request)
        HttpListenerContext context = _listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        string html = Properties.Resources.index;

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        _ouput = response.OutputStream;
        _ouput.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Then if you if you use your data and use a try catch then you can set the bool false if there is an exceptioon or you can continue the function so it will go out of the loop.

You can get your data like this:

```
HttpListenerContext httpContext = _listener.GetContext();
HttpListenerRequest httpRequest = context.Request;

if ( request.HttpMethod == "POST" )
{

}
```

And for the Javascript part, just keep it nice and easy. I've used something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            var delayrec = {};
            function delay(callback, id, calldelay) {
                clearTimeout(delayrec[id]);
                delayrec[id] = setTimeout(callback, calldelay);
            }

            function verzenden(event) {
                var keycode = document.getElementById("form_keycode");

                if (event.keyCode == 125 || event.keyCode == 113) {                   
                    keycode.value = 125;
                }
                else if (event.keyCode == 126 || event.keyCode == 115) {                    
                    keycode.value = 126;
                }

                delay(function () {
                    document.myform.submit();
                }, "submitlocatie", 500);
            }

            function load() {
                var locatie = document.getElementById("locatie");
                var bonregel = document.getElementById("bonregel");
                if (locatie.value == "")
                    locatie.focus();
                else
                    bonregel.focus();
            }

            $(document).keydown(function (eventObject) {
                alert(eventObject.keyCode);
            });



        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <fieldset>
                <legend> test</legend><br />
                <form name="myform" action="/" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" id="keycode" name="keycode" />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Text1:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="textfield1" name="textfield1" onkeyup="verzenden(event)" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Text2:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="textfield2" name="textfield2" onkeyup="verzenden(event)" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <p id="errorSection">{errorSection}</p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I use the keyCode events to send the data, and cancel the sending.

I hope this helps and good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpListenerRequest` and check if the method type is `POST`

```
HttpListenerContext context = _listener.GetContext();
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

if ( request.HttpMethod == "POST" )
{

}
```

You can read and show the POST data as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23257514/1099945)

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery Ajax call on client side. Let's assume your input fields ids are input1 and input2 and submit button has id = submitBtn. You can do smth like this:

```
$(window).load(function () {            // after browser has loaded win
   $('#submitBtn').click(function() {   // add button click handler
        var inp1 = $('#input1').val();  // get value from input 1
        var inp2 = $('#input2').val();  // get value from input 2
                $.ajax({                // send ajax POST request on server
                    url: "http://localhost:8000/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {input1:inp1 , input2:inp2}, 
                }).done(function () {
                    ...your logic on success
                    ...for example - location.reload();
                }).fail(function (err) {
                    alert(err.statusText);
                });
    });
});
```

Don't forget to include Jquery library to your html document.

```
smth like <script src=".../jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: I think plain JS would be easier on mu side

Comment: You know, one of main reasons why JQuery was created it is because it's a lot easier !  Try it and you'll be ok

Comment: Yes i understand but i have to work with older browsers like ie5