# How to get the filename with the extension when making a POST request?

Tags: c#, .net, console, httplistener

I'm trying to retrieve the filename when I make a request, below I have the filename print but I can't retrieve it.

[image]

I'm making the request as follows, using postman

[image]

Follow the full code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunServer();
}

public static void RunServer()
{
    var prefix = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/file/";
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
    try
    {
        listener.Start();
    }
    catch (HttpListenerException hlex)
    {
        return;
    }
    while (listener.IsListening)
    {
        var context = listener.GetContext();
        ProcessRequest(context);
    }
    listener.Close();
}

private static void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
{
    // Get the data from the HTTP stream
    var body = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

    byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ACK");
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.KeepAlive = false;
    context.Response.ContentLength64 = b.Length;

    var output = context.Response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    context.Response.Close();
}
```

To try to recover the file name I tried to do it in the way below.

```
var body = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(body, "filename\\=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\"");
string filename = null;
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    if (m.Success) filename = Regex.Replace(m.Value, "filename\\=","").Replace("\"","");
}
```

Is there a better way to get the filename? appreciate

Comment: Content-disposition, Name and Content-type are _HTTP Headers_, you need to pull them out of the response

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Try looking at the `Headers` property of the `response`. The internet has pretty good search tools

Comment: There really isn't a better way - see this (duplicate) question [Getting form data from HttpListenerRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197579/getting-form-data-from-httplistenerrequest)

Comment: @Flydog57 All form data on `HttpListenerContext.Request` is part of the `InputStream` - there is no way to pull that data from headers directly via this class.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thank you very much, I'll check the link